# Python, shutil.move превратил папки в неопознанные файлы

Tags: python, shutil

```
def sort_files(dir): 
list_dir = os.listdir(dir) 
anim_dir = os.path.join(dir, 'animation') 
pic_dir = os.path.join(dir, 'pics')  

# Сортировка файлов по папкам 
for name in list_dir: 
    file_path = fr'{dir}\{name}' 
    try: 
        if pics_anim(file_path): 
            shutil.move(file_path, anim_dir) 
        else: 
            shutil.move(file_path, pic_dir) 
    except: 
        print(f'Ошибка с этим файлом: {file_path}')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По плану должно было быть две папки и внутри у них отсортированные файлы, а теперь нету файлов и папки вместо них два таких НЛО. Где теперь мои файлы? как вернуть их. а там было больше 200 файлов. Что делать??

Comment: что делать что делать. Брать утерянные файлы из бэкапа. Если его нет, то сказать "до свидания" своим "больше 200" файлов. Впрочем, два из них остались. Вижу тут следующие ошибки: 1. Не знаешь, что делает функция shutil.move. 2. Не умеешь ей пользоваться. 3. Не читал руководство к этой функции. 4. Не тестировал код на безопасных данных. 5. (скорее всего) не делаешь бэкапы.

Comment: Да уж... я тупой... Я так понел функция переместила их в никуда и тем самым файлы уничтожились... Я даже пробовал восстановить их с программой Hetman Partition Recovery, но увы не находит.

Comment: Не в никуда, а в файлы ``animation`` и ``pics``. Но каждый следующий файл затирал предыдущий, поэтому осталось только два последних.